# Is there a standard notation to express the "partial inverse" of a multivariate function?

Tags: notation, inverse-function

Consider the function

$$ y = f(x,w) $$

I am looking for "proper" notation for the "partial inverse" of $f(\cdot)$ with respect to each variable. Something like:

$$ x = f^{-1}(y,w) $$

$$ w = f^{-1}(x,y) $$

But this does not differentiate them. Perhaps

$$ x = f_x^{-1}(y,w) $$

$$ w = f_w^{-1}(x,y) $$

But this might be confused with derivative of the inverse.

Actually, it seems using "inverse" notation is not proper (see [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/53236728#53236728) for full discussion).

I can always revert to new functions, like

$$ x = h(y,w) $$

$$ w = g(x,y) $$

but this is inferior in two ways: it does not show the direct relation between $f(\cdot)$, $h(\cdot)$ and $g(\cdot)$; and it introduces more notation. I'm looking for economy and efficacy.

So, the question is:

What is the notation used to express the "partial inverse" of a multivariate function, like above?